# Observability Gramian of an Unscented Kalman Filter not Matching Estimation Results

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-analysis, kalman-filter

I am running an unscented Kalman filter on my system and am able to estimate the states within 4% of their true values. This is true with a Monte Carlo simulation consisting of 1000 runs. However, when checking the observability Gramian of the system, I am finding that the matrix is not full rank.

Is it possible to estimate states well using a UKF without all the states being observable?

My system is nonlinear, so to calculate the Gramian I first calculate the state transition matrix of the dynamics (Phi) for each time step. I then compute Phi' * H' * H * Phi' at each time step, where H is the Jacobian of the measurement matrix. I sum these matrices to obtain the observability Gramian at the end of the simulation and find that it is not full rank.

Any insight into my problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but might point you in the right direction. Observability is not required for the estimate of a (uncented) Kalman filter to converge, instead a slightly weaker notion of detectability is required. Also note that your way of determining observability uses an approximation (since nonlinear systems can't be described by state transition matrices, instead normally Lie derivatives are used which is similar to the observability matrix), so using such an approximation might give unreliable results.